# Kafka Listener could not consume message and persist to hbase table

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, hbase, spring-kafka

I have an application for logging transactions to hbase tables. I am consuming transactions messages from kafka but my kafka listener logging following lines. And could not persist to hbase table. I am using for consumer spring-kafka 2.1.7 release. How can i resolve this issue? My kafka consumer implementation like that;

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.consumer.topic}")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) throws IOException {
    if (StringUtils.hasText(consumerRecord.value())) {
     //Some business logic
    }
}
```

Kafka Listener Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerProperties kafkaListenerProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =  new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
//        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps(), stringKeyDeserializer(), workUnitJsonValueDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerProperties.getBootstrap());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaListenerProperties.getGroup());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
//        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public Deserializer stringKeyDeserializer() {
        return new StringDeserializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Deserializer workUnitJsonValueDeserializer() {
        return new StringDeserializer();
    }

}
```

Kafka Listener-Hbase logging like following;

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] #106, waiting for some tasks to finish. Expected max=0, tasksInProgress=2 hasError=false, tableName=FraudRequest

INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] Left over 2 task(s) are processed on server(s): [XXXXX.kfs.local,60020,1552673278405]

INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] Regions against which left over task(s) are processed: [FraudRequest,15543323,1554891506303.d3bb6fef4ab349e93729d14d13f730bc.]

INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] #107, waiting for some tasks to finish. Expected max=0, tasksInProgress=2 hasError=false, tableName=FraudRequest

INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] Left over 2 task(s) are processed on server(s): [XXXXX.kfs.local,60020,1552673278405]

INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] Regions against which left over task(s) are processed: [FraudRequest,15543323,1554891506303.d3bb6fef4ab349e93729d14d13f730bc.]
```

Comment: can you share more logs? your expected value is of type String. can you change the method signature from consumer record to ```Message``` or some String value like ```public void receive(String consumerRecord)``` or message ```public void receive(Message consumerRecord)```

Comment: Thanks for response, I added some logs but already have same log. I changed receive method parameter to String and problem continue